# Open an activity from all activity on right swipe

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, scroll, swipe

I have a dashboard activity . I Want this activity to open from any screen of my app (from any activity) on right swipe on screen.if some screen has horizontal scroll then scroll will complete and then dashboard will open.i don't want to implement swipe in every single activity.pls give some idea

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling intent..

put this class global package.

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 1;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
                result = true;
            } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom();
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop();
                }
            }
            result = true;

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}}
```

and use the class for every activity you need to bring your Dashboard activity

For ex: sampleActivity.class

```
switch_action.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(Camera.this) {

        @Override
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            super.onSwipeRight();
            startActivity(new Intent(sampleActivity.this,Dashboard.class));
        }
    });
```

switchAction is transparent Relative Layout you need use in sample Activity constraint will

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/switch_action"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

so once user swipe in the screen switchaction will get called you can startActivity as your need..

Comment: Ashokkumar Adichili as i said i can't add this code in every activity because i have lots of activities .is there any way to get swipe event on top window of screen of my app